# crawling with curl - just cant get it right

Tags: php, curl

So i am pullin item data and the rest

I am unable to get ItemDataCosts

I am pulling al the json thats not an array inside an array- but item data cost i am unable to get

If any body can point me in the correct direction

with

```
echo "<br>ItemDataCosts start<br>"; 

foreach($result->ItemData->ItemDataCosts as $ItemDataCosts) {
echo $ItemDataCosts->Seq.'Seq<br>';
echo $ItemDataCosts->FUnitPrice.'FUnitPrice<br>';
echo $ItemDataCosts->Currencies_Seq.'Currencies_Seq<br>'; 
}
echo "<br>ItemDataCosts end<br>";
```

This is what is returned from json

```
 "ItemData"
  ]=>array(4){
    [
      0
    ]=>array(46){
  [
    "BookStatus"
  ]=>int(3)[
    "BookNotes"
  ]=>array(2){
    [
      "SupplierReference"
    ]=>string(0)""[
      "Details"
    ]=>string(85)" Cancelled on: 7/23/2018 12:58:07 PM BRBK1H Booked on: 3/9/2018 1:15:23 PM "
  }[

    "Allocated"
  ]=>bool(false)[
    "StartDate"
  ]=>string(20)"2018-08-05T14:00:00Z"[
    "CostPriceCompo"
  ]=>NULL[
    "GTABookingHeaders"
  ]=>array(0){

  }[
    "ProductTariff"
  ]=>NULL[
    "QuoteProp"
  ]=>NULL[
    "ItemDataCosts"
  ]=>array(1){
    [
      0
    ]=>array(19){
      [
        "Seq"
      ]=>float(720949)[
        "ItemData_Seq"
      ]=>float(140)[
        "UnitPrice"
      ]=>float(819)
    }
  }
```

and i get the json with below php curl - the output is wat i got then i take that and paste in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu and then format to view the fields

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$url = 'https://my.travpro.cloud/api//costings/getcosting/*****';

$auth = base64_encode('paul.******:******3');
$postfields = http_build_query( array(
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'));
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization: Basic $auth"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: You can either store the JSON result as TEXT in MySQL - or first convert the JSON into array by `json_decode($json,TRUE)` and then do the mapping between this JSON and your data model. As you know, relational databases require tabular data - exactly like an Excel sheet.

Comment: thisis the json after json_decode?

Comment: **Please** format your question properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: First line of what ? The API returns array of arrays - so you simply specify the correct indices to get from the root to the desired node and then simply enumerate the elements of that array node. Just like you do with Passengers.

Comment: ok i am getting most of the information

Comment: please look at code amended, i need to get the item_data_costs info

Answer (score 0):

ItemData (according to your array-ified JSON) is array. Using `->` will not work on it, but `$result->ItemData['ItemDataCosts']` should do. 
so this should work:

```
$result = json_decode($response);
echo "<br>ItemDataCosts start<br>";
$itemData = $result->{'ItemData'};
foreach($itemData as $ItemData) {
    foreach($itemData as $item) {
        $itemDataCosts = $item->{'ItemDataCosts'};
        foreach($itemDataCosts as  $itemDataCost) {
            echo $itemDataCost->{'Seq'} . 'Seq<br>';
            echo $itemDataCost->{'FUnitPrice'} . 'FUnitPrice<br>';
            echo $itemDataCost->{'Currencies_Seq'} . 'Currencies_Seq<br>';
        }
    }
}
echo "<br>ItemDataCosts end<br>";
```

Comment: foreach($result->ItemData['ItemDataCosts'] as $ItemDataCosts) {    
     echo $ItemDataCosts->Seq.'Seq<br>';
     echo $ItemDataCosts->ItemData_Seq.'ItemData_Seq<br>';

Comment: Stil no data returned

Comment: that's because each datacost is also an array (look up the hints on var_dump). 
stop using notation `->` on arrays and it will work ;)
Also, please enable error reporting. PHP will report those wrong references and will tell you what's wrong, too.

Comment: i am brand new- noob on json. I have no clue what you just tried to explain to me?  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: please attach the JSON to the question and I'll show you the code to get to the `ItemData_Seq` with PHP

Comment: ItemDataCosts start

Notice: Use of undefined constant ItemDataCosts - assumed 'ItemDataCosts'

Comment: in the pastebin, there is not JSON, it's resulting var_dump. 
However your code says: Notice: Use of undefined constant ItemDataCosts so your code is:
`->ItemData[ItemDataCosts]` when it should be `>ItemData['ItemDataCosts']`. then, within the loop, each cost is also an array, so you should be able to reference to it using `$ItemDataCosts['Seq']`

Comment: added your code but modified to be used with arrays to the response

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Dx7Zemrr    ItemDataCosts start

Notice: Undefined index: ItemDataCosts in /var/www/html/travelit/aac.php on line 109

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/travelit/aac.php on line 109
 after changing to your code

Comment: You're missing the basics. Please read on what JSON is then post a link to actual JSON content.

Comment: i am doing this as this is the respose   $response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($response);

Comment: I know, but I need the JSON you're trying to parse.

Comment: please check my code - that is the response i am getting - json decode

Comment: I know it's not all OR you're not reading what I posted in the answer. If `$result` is an object with `ItemData` property, and it contains an array then my example code will work. If it doesn't, please post JSON or do not expect any other answer, sorry.

Comment: I already stated this 3 times: I don't need var_dump, I need JSON. The text response formatted in JSON.

Comment: I clearly do not understand what you are saying, as i do not have the original json, its from a client website that i curl url = 'https://my.travpro.cloud/api//costings/getcosting/; and then with curl i get this response. What do i need to change

Comment: if i just type in the header without en coding i get this   https://pastebin.com/vMH8RRN0

Comment: finally a JSON. thank you and see updated code in my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer by googling a lot here is what works

```
$this_data = $result->ItemData;

foreach($this_data as $key){
    foreach($key->ItemDataCosts as $values){
        echo '<pre>';
        echo $values->ItemData_Seq . ' ItemData Sequence';
        echo $values->FUnitPrice . ' Unit Price';
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
die();
```